# How much weight can the studs in a non load bearing wall support?

Tags: walls

I have a non load bearing wall in my home that has a 52' inch LCD TV mounted into the studs. I think the TV weighs around 90lb

I'd like to add another shelf underneath the TV to the same wall mounted to the studs, the shelf should weigh less than 70lb.

The house was built in 1927 and is raised off the ground. Not on cement.

Should the wall be able to hold the two items weighing a total of 160-170 lbs?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this question: [How much weight can you mount to a wall?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5958/how-much-weight-can-you-mount-to-a-wall)

Comment: How far apart are the studs, and how many are you anchoring into?

Answer (score 4):

Non-load bearing means that it doesn't have the weight of the roof and ceiling bearing on it, basically, it can be removed with no ill effects. This has no bearing whatsoever on its capacity to hold a load, which has more to do with how the wall is tied in with the floor and roof joists. If you had a modern home I wouldn't worry about it. Since your home is (probably) not up to modern building codes you could have a professional mount it and thus bear any liability for the failure of the wall. If that isn't an option, inspect the condition and spacing of your studs and the anchoring of the wall into the floor and ceiling.